# auto increment primary key value gives null values error

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, spring-mvc

I am trying to insert data into Microsoft server management studio table using "Spring MVC" project.

Contact id has been set as `NOT NULL` and `AUTO INCREMENT by 1`. Even it is trying to insert null.

I have define `user id` primary key not null and identity 1. Here is the query to create table :

```
CREATE TABLE contact (
  contact_id[int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  address varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  telephone varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (contact_id)
)
```

Table design:

[image: table]

Error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SpringDispatcher] in context with path [/SpringMvcJdbcTemplate] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO contact (name, email, address, telephone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]; Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'contact_id', table 'contactdb.dbo.contact'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'contact_id', table 'contactdb.dbo.contact'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.] with root cause
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'contact_id', table 'contactdb.dbo.contact'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

code lines:

// insert

```
    String sql = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, address, telephone)"
                + " VALUES ('" + contact.getName() + "', '" + contact.getEmail() + "', '" + contact.getAddress() + "', '" + contact.getTelephone() + "')";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
```

**UPDATE**

```
CREATE TABLE contact (
  contact_id int IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(45) ,
  email varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  address varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  telephone varchar(45) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: try "identity(1,1)" in the updated statement

Comment: And stop putting values in your SQL like that - use a prepared statement. See http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: See for values going in other NOT NULL columns.Identity column seems fine

Comment: @Anand FYI specifying just "Identity" is the same as "identity(1,1)". There is no difference in the resulting behavior; they both start at 1 and increment by 1.

Comment: @cyclic Open SQL Server's profiler on this SQL instance and select the "Replay" template then attempt to do an insert through your Java code. Capture and analyze the generated statement and post it here please. Another thing to try: do a manual insert in to "contact" via TSQL statement (not from your Java code). Does it also fail? Are there any triggers on this table?

Comment: @artofsql: thanks dear, manual insertion was working fine. I figured out. there was silly mistake in database name mismatch. apologize

Answer (score 0):

Create a procedure or add a SCOPE_IDENTITY() method in default value.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Usuallly when providing a answer, you should aim for atleast 5-6 lines with a code example and proably some links. Otherwise your answer looks more like a comment.